# Injecting transaction in OSGi reference listener with blueprint

Tags: osgi, blueprint-osgi, aries

I have an OSGi bundle which has a reference listener class keeping track of services registered by other OSGi bundles. I have configured the reference listener with blueprint as follows and have deployed all the necessary Aries bundles in Felix:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
xmlns:jpa="http://aries.apache.org/xmlns/jpa/v1.0.0" xmlns:tx="http://aries.apache.org/xmlns/transactions/v1.0.0">  
    <reference-list id="ServiceList" interface="com.test.MyService" availability="optional">
        <reference-listener bind-method="bind" unbind-method="unbind">
            <bean class="com.test.MyServiceMonitor" />
        </reference-listener>
    </reference-list>
</blueprint>
```

Everything works well with this configuration and the bind and unbind methods of the MyServiceMonitor class are called when services come and go. As a next step I want the bind method to also write some data in the database so I tried to inject an entity manager in MyServiceMonitor and create a transaction by changing the bean tag as follows:

```
<bean class="com.test.MyServiceMonitor">
    <tx:transaction method="bind" value="RequiresNew" />
    <jpa:context property="entityManager" unitname="myunit" />
</bean>
```

This attempt to create a transaction for the bind method results to the exception below when I start the bundle. The bundle is started without problems when I remove the tx:transaction tag while I have been able to use an entity manager and transactions in other (non reference listener) beans with the same blueprint configuration.

Being relatively new to OSGi I haven't been able to figure out whether this is expected behaviour and if yes what is the proper way to perform DB operations inside a reference listener. Any insights on that?

```
2013-07-11 12:40:12,592 | ERROR | 20 - org.apache.aries.blueprint - 1.1.0 | org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl | Unable to start blueprint container for bundle com.test.my-bundle
org.osgi.service.blueprint.container.ComponentDefinitionException: Unable to convert value BeanRecipe[name='#recipe-2'] to type class java.lang.Object
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.CollectionRecipe.internalCreate(CollectionRecipe.java:92)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:106)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.AbstractServiceReferenceRecipe.createListeners(AbstractServiceReferenceRecipe.java:246)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.ReferenceListRecipe.internalCreate(ReferenceListRecipe.java:74)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe$1.call(AbstractRecipe.java:79)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:88)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createInstances(BlueprintRepository.java:245)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createAll(BlueprintRepository.java:183)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.instantiateEagerComponents(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:668)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.doRun(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:370)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.run(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:261)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.ExecutorServiceWrapper.run(ExecutorServiceWrapper.java:106)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.threading.impl.DiscardableRunnable.run(DiscardableRunnable.java:48)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.osgi.service.blueprint.container.ComponentDefinitionException: Error setting property: PropertyDescriptor <name: listener, getter: null, setter: [class org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.AbstractServiceReferenceRecipe$Listener.setListener(class java.lang.Object)]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.setProperty(BeanRecipe.java:941)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.setProperties(BeanRecipe.java:907)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.setProperties(BeanRecipe.java:888)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate2(BeanRecipe.java:820)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate(BeanRecipe.java:787)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:106)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.CollectionRecipe.internalCreate(CollectionRecipe.java:90)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.osgi.service.blueprint.container.ComponentDefinitionException: Unable to create proxy for bean #recipe-3 in bundle com.test.my-bundle version 1.0.0.SNAPSHOT
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.addInterceptors(BeanRecipe.java:771)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.wrap(BeanRecipe.java:841)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.AggregateConverter.convert(AggregateConverter.java:149)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.convert(BlueprintRepository.java:402)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.ReflectionUtils$PropertyDescriptor.convert(ReflectionUtils.java:394)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.ReflectionUtils$MethodPropertyDescriptor.internalSet(ReflectionUtils.java:628)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.ReflectionUtils$PropertyDescriptor.set(ReflectionUtils.java:378)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.setProperty(BeanRecipe.java:939)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: org.apache.aries.proxy.UnableToProxyException: The class com.test.MyServiceMonitor is not an interface and therefore a proxy cannot be generated.
    at org.apache.aries.proxy.impl.JdkProxyManager.getInterfaces(JdkProxyManager.java:43)
    at org.apache.aries.proxy.impl.JdkProxyManager.createNewProxy(JdkProxyManager.java:36)
    at org.apache.aries.proxy.impl.AbstractProxyManager.createDelegatingInterceptingProxy(AbstractProxyManager.java:75)
    at org.apache.aries.proxy.impl.AbstractProxyManager.createInterceptingProxy(AbstractProxyManager.java:53)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.addInterceptors(BeanRecipe.java:767)
    ... 38 more
```

Comment: Does MyServiceMonitor implement an interface?

Comment: @SheenaArtrip No, it doesn't since it's not necessary for the reference listener to work.

Answer (score 0):

Your transaction manager is using JdkProxyManager to proxy transactions. The built in JDK proxy manager requires an interface in order to proxy. Best bet is to make an interface with the required methods and implement it. The other option is to switch to an ASM, CGLib or JavaAssist based ProxyManager.

Comment: I tried creating an interface which defines the methods I want to make transactional and having MyServiceMonitor class implement this interface but I still get the same exception. I even tried exposing it as a service (which ideally I wouldn't want to have to do) but still no luck. Am I missing something in the blueprint configuration perhaps?